# How to get Build Id from tfs during the build in C#

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild

To get a log link i need the id of current build, I tried to use this in my C# code, but it didn't return Build Id:

```
var envVars;
envVars = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
```

Comment: What version of Team Foundation Server are you using? What build template/process is used for your builds?

Comment: tfs 2017, and i really don't know what process is used

Comment: how is the code invoked ? also you need so search for "build.buildid". i don't know what "runId" is supposed to be

Comment: GetEnvironmentVariables(); doesn't give me any build variables

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution is to put this var in txt file via PowerShell script, and than get it by C#

PS:

```
    if(!(Test-Path -Path C:\BuildVariables)){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path C:\BuildVariables
}

Out-File -FilePath C:\BuildVariables\buildId.txt -Force -InputObject $(Build.Buildid)
```

C#:

```
public static string ShowEnvironmentVariables()
{
    string var = File.ReadAllText("C:\\BuildVariables\\buildId.txt");

    return var;
}
```

Comment: I can't see why you couldn't just skip the PowerShell, and just pass `Build.BuildId` into the C# app as an argument?

Comment: Cuz it is not exists in current environment

Answer (score 0):

To get the `Build.Id` during the build with C# you can try this line:

```
string buildId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Build_BuildId", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the build Id from this variable

$(Build.BuildId)

Pass it as parameter(exactly as it written here) to the tool(console app?) that you are building.

You can check other variables from this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml